# PHP String: How to replace all " to inches and ' to foot?

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to replace all `'` to `foot` word and `"` to `inches` word.

I also need to remove all the enclosed double quote and single quote in a word.

The final output should be:

```
start Rica's 5-1/8 inches another 7 inches here Week 5 foot again 7 foot last clean again hello Mark's end
```

Below is my quick sample code - not yet working.

```
<?php
$title = 'start Rica\'s 5-1/8" another 7" here ""Week" 5\' again 7\' last \'clean\' again \'hello\' Mark\'s end';

$inches = '"';
$foot = "'";
$inches_word = ' inches';
$foot_word = " foot";

//$pos = strpos($title, $foot);
$pos_inches = strpos($title, $inches);
// check if before the " or ' is a number
$check_number_inches = substr($title, $pos_inches - 1, 1);
if (is_numeric($check_number_inches)) {
    // replace " to inches
    $title = str_replace($inches, $inches_word, $title);
}

$pos_foot = strpos($title, $foot);
// check if before the " or ' is a number
$check_number_foot = substr($title, $pos_foot - 1, 1);
if (is_numeric($check_number_foot)) {
    // replace " to inches
    $title = str_replace($foot, $foot_word, $title);
}

echo $title;
?>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the question here? Are you having a problem with a specific line of code?

Comment: Though it could get a lot more complex if you wanted to test the value of the numeric to see if you should use foot or feet, and inch or inches

Comment: you could use feet like in your solution and then use str_replace on " 1 feet" or something like that (depending on how it can occur, in the text above it only is behind a " " and a "/" for a fraction, but that is not possible for a 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a regex based solution is acceptable you can do:

```
$title = preg_replace(array("/(\d+)'/","/(\d+)\"/",'/"/',"/'(?!s)/"),
                      array('\1 foot','\1 inches','',''),
                      $title);
```

[**Ideone Link**](http://www.ideone.com/2ms0G)

Answer (score 1):

You only want to replace ' or " when they appear after a numeric, so use regular expressions with preg_replace() for this

```
$title = 'start Rica\'s 5-1/8" another 7" here ""Week" 5\' again 7\' last \'clean\' again \'hello\' Mark\'s end';

$fromArray = array('/(\d\s*)"/',
                   "/(\d\s*)'/");
$toArray = array('$1 inches', 
                 '$1 foot');


$title = preg_replace($fromArray,$toArray,$title);
```

which gives:

```
start Rica's 5-1/8 inches another 7 inches here ""Week" 5 foot again 7 foot last 'clean' again 'hello' Mark's end
```